# Cannot understand why stopping a thread normally will hang the remaining execution code from that thread in (wx)Python under Windows

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I have a wxPython code, running under Windows 10 64bit / Python 3.9.0 64bit / wx '4.1.1 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5', that starts a thread in an external file (if that matters in any way for my problem). The real code starts a telnet session, but for simplicity (and understanding) I created a separate working test program, shown below, that follows the same logic as the real code, except that it has the telnet part removed.

The program has a "Connect" toolbar button that starts a thread with reporting message on status bar and a "Disconnect" button that should stop the thread normally (well, at least that was my intention) again with a reporting message on status bar.

By clicking the "Connect" button on toolbar (i.e. the "+" button), the thread starts OK.

My problem: as far as I click the "Disconnect" button on toolbar (i.e. the "-" button), the program hangs, supposedly because of an endless thread execution. It is like the `stopped` function freezes everything, not just letting the `while ...` loop to leave and simply follows its way out.

By changing the thread's loop `while not self.stopped():` statement with something like `while True` followed by  `break` triggered by a couple of seconds timeout (thus, without further touching the "Disconnect" button), the thread exits normally after the timeout as if nothing has happened – so the problem is with the actual thread stop mechanism.

However, while running the same test program under Raspberry Pi OS (Buster) / Python 3.7.3 / wx '4.0.7 post2 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5', the hanging no longer occurs (I get there some Gtk-WARNING & random Gdk-ERROR, most likely due to some imperfection on my simplified wx test code, but I simply ignored that for now).

Perhaps this is not a Windows-specific problem, perhaps the logic of my program has some flaw.

What do I miss here ?

Note: for the simplicity of this test, the close button of the program window does not try to end the thread (if started) prior to program exit and the "Disconnect" button event does not check if there is actually something to disconnect.

**Later edit**: I tested it, under same Windows, also with Python 3.9.1 32bit / wx '4.1.1 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5' (this one installed using pip of the 32bit Python install): no difference, the program hangs the same way.

Main code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import test_wx_th_ext_file as TestWxThExtFile

import wx
import threading
import time
import os
import sys

##

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.SetTitle("test wx th")

        self.frame_statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar(1)
        self.frame_statusbar.SetStatusWidths([-1])

        # Tool Bar
        self.frame_toolbar = wx.ToolBar(self, -1)
        tool = self.frame_toolbar.AddTool(wx.ID_ANY, "Connect", wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_PLUS, wx.ART_TOOLBAR, (24, 24)), wx.NullBitmap, wx.ITEM_NORMAL, "Connect", "")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.ctrl_connect, id=tool.GetId())
        tool = self.frame_toolbar.AddTool(wx.ID_ANY, "Disconnect", wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_MINUS, wx.ART_TOOLBAR, (24, 24)), wx.NullBitmap, wx.ITEM_NORMAL, "Disconnect", "")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.ctrl_disconnect, id=tool.GetId())
        self.SetToolBar(self.frame_toolbar)
        self.frame_toolbar.Realize()
        # Tool Bar end

        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.Layout()

    def ctrl_connect(self, event):
        self.ctrl_thread = TestWxThExtFile.ControllerTn(self)
        self.ctrl_thread.daemon = True
        self.ctrl_thread.start()

    def ctrl_disconnect(self, event):
        self.ctrl_thread.stopit()
        self.ctrl_thread.join()

##

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

##

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
    try:
        sys.exit(0)
    except SystemExit:
        os._exit(0)
```

and code on external file (actual thread):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import threading
import time

##

class ControllerTh(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._stopper = threading.Event()

    def stopit(self):
        self._stopper.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stopper.is_set()

##

class ControllerTn(ControllerTh):
    def __init__(self, wx_ui):
        ControllerTh.__init__(self)
        self.wx_ui = wx_ui
  
    def run(self):
        print ("th_enter")
        self.wx_ui.frame_statusbar.SetStatusText("Connected")

        while not self.stopped():
            print ("th_loop")
            time.sleep(1)

        self.wx_ui.frame_statusbar.SetStatusText("Disconnected")
        print ("th_exit")
```

The test window (under Windows) looks like this (shown here right after clicking the "Connect" button on toolbar):

[image: wx interface in 'connected' status]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have to admit this is non-intuitive at first. Tried to leave out the `self.ctrl_thread.join()`. This is the true cause of your issue and you would need to think of another way how to safely stop the thread.

To make it run, move the UI-specific status bar update from the thread back to the frame. Problem solved. In the thread:

```
    while not self.stopped():
        print ("th_loop")
        time.sleep(1)

    # move this to the frame
    # self.wx_ui.frame_statusbar.SetStatusText("Disconnected")
    print ("th_exit")
```

In the frame:

```
    def ctrl_disconnect(self, event):
        self.ctrl_thread.stopit()
        self.ctrl_thread.join()
        # thread has joined, signal end of thread
        self.frame_statusbar.SetStatusText("Disconnected")
```

I suppose you were not convinced about the thread exiting by itself, because you are killing everything at the end anyway :)

```
# hooray, all threads will be dead :)
try:
    sys.exit(0)
except SystemExit:
    os._exit(0)
```

In a nutshell, in wxPython code you **must** never have code which blocks, because it will prevent any further code being processed. Enter threads.

In your case, the wx event loop enters your method `ctrl_disconnect`. The `join()` means it is waiting for the thread to stop. However, your code in the thread tries to get wxPython to ececute code (`self.wx_ui.frame_statusbar.SetStatusText`), which cannot proceed because the wxPython loop is still waiting for `join()` to finish.

Comment: Well, the answer here is in your statement *in wxPython code you **must** never have code which blocks, because it will prevent any further code being processed*. Indeed, the problem was with the ```.join()``` **fact** (not method), since I tried also some other different waiting methods for the thread to close, which actually locked the program in the same way. Moving the UI-specific status bar update proved to be of no importance (I tried to remove it completely before) and also not a solution, as in my real code the thread must write several other messages there. All in all, thank you :)

Comment: (continue from above comment, as it was too long) Still, I cannot understand why this test works "as is" on Raspberry Pi (i.e. Linux); that completely confused me.

Comment: Do not worry: tried your code as posted in the question on a Debian 64bit Buster (``apt install python3-wxgtk4.0``). It would crash on pressing connect. Had to move out also the first call to wxPython from the thread. I think the raspbian wxPython is buggy enough it will let you get away with thread mishandling :)

Another note: wxPython is not thread-safe. Therefore the recommendation is to use wx.CallAfter (which **is** thread-safe) from the non-wx thread.

Comment: Like this: ``wx.CallAfter(self.wx_ui.frame_statusbar.SetStatusText, "Disconnected")``. And you might have guessed it: This will work on Debian, but not on Windows :/

Comment: I tested the ```wx.CallAfter(self.etc.)``` as suggested above and it works well both on Windows and Raspberry Pi OS :) This, combined with the main solution as resulted from the accepted answer (i.e. avoiding/removing any waiting/blocking code), resulted in a more robust working program. Thank you :)

Comment: I can confirm that: Essentially to make your original code work on Windows and Debian 64bit it was sufficient to wrap the calls with ``wx.CallAfter``, as is the standard recommendation for threads in wx docs anyways. And one last caveat: why did ``wx.CallAfter`` not work for me in Windows in the first try: look what I did and spot the fine difference: ``wx.CallAfter(self.wx_ui.frame_statusbar.SetStatusText("Disconnected"))`` – passing a function **call**, not a **reference**